# Execute Listbox_SelectionIndex or Listbox_Tap before executing UserControlCheckbox_Checked

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8, listbox

I have a **Listbox implemented in page**. It uses my user control as its items. My **user control** includes textbox,image,and a checkbox.

**Case 1:**
When I click on image in listbox item, it goes to **Listbox_SelectionIndex()** , then to **UserControlImage_Tap()** and then to **Listbox_Tap()**. It takes selectionindex from Listbox_SelectionIndex() in mainpage , and on this selectionindex it works in UserControlImage_Tap() method in usercontrol code and then moves back to  Listbox_Tap() in mainpage.

**Case 2:**
Now in case of checking/unchecking the checkbox, it directly executes **UserControlCheckbox_Checked()** method from usercontrol code. It skips executing **Listbox_SelectionIndex()** from mainpage first. It means i am not able to send selectionindex to **UserControlCheckbox_Checked()**.

How to achieve this?

---

I tried setting  IsHitTestVisible="False" in XAML for checkbox in usercontrol. It works,  now ListBox_SelectionChanged() gets executed first, but again of no use, because in my ListBox_SelectionChanged() i have a navigate to another page. so when I check on checkbox, before checking/unchecking it,  user is getting navigating.

```
  public void ListBox_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            if (ListBoxHindi.SelectedIndex != -1)
            {
           NavigationIndexHindi=ListBoxHindi.SelectedIndex;
                singletonInstance.HindiTouchedIndex = NavigationIndexHindi;
                NavigationService.Navigate(new Uri(singletonInstance.GotoContentDisplayPage + "?language=" + LanguageType + "&bookToOpenIndex=" + NavigationIndexHindi, UriKind.Relative));
                        ListBoxHindi.SelectedIndex = -1;
            }
        }



    public void ListBox_Tap(object sender, System.Windows.Input.GestureEventArgs e)
    {

        if (ListBoxHindi.SelectedIndex != -1)
        {
            singletonInstance.HindiTouchedIndex = ListBoxHindi.SelectedIndex; 
            ListBoxHindi.SelectedIndex = -1;
        }

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to add Try/Catch or If statement - If is that chackbox chacked, execute and continue... Else simply continue...